# How to use float in SQL for amount

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field called T_Amount data type is float,

```
e.g= T_Amount=11800

When i make formula in query (11800/24)*35.25=17331.25

but actually if i make in calculator (11800/24)*35.25=17331.24999

i want this full figure.
```

Comment: `Float/real` - approximate datatypes, `DECIMAL/NUMERIC/MONEY` exact datatype

Comment: @lad2025 It's not a precision issue. It's a division issue

Comment: `DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL(10,4) = 11800;

SELECT (@Amount/24)*35.25 --17331,249997650` **[Demo](http://rextester.com/HCUJ25772)**

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Datatype is crucial.

Comment: @lad2025 Exactly, but the example is using integer division where the question think it's using decimal based division. Hence it's not a precision issue and therefore not a approximated datatype issue (and not a duplicate either)

Comment: OP says: `T_Amount data type is float` And I treated `11800` as variable of type `FLOAT`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/PTBHE37587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your division is interpreted as an integer division because you have two integers being divided.

If you do the following you'll get a more decimal characters:

```
SELECT (11800/24.0)*35.25
```

Which returns: 
`17331.24997650`

So you need to be sure that you have 'float' values inside the division as well. So use decimal instead of float for division.

Comment: then for getting this value what should i do?

Comment: You should make sure that 11800 and/or 24 is cast as a decimal number and not an integer in the division. As you can see in my example, I'm using `24.0` instead of only `24`

Comment: SELECT (11800.00000/24)*35.25 will give you the result with greater precision. So declare T_Amount (10,5) or your desired precision